# How to select record in 1 to many relation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a contact table and contactphone tables.

Each record in contacts can have many records in contactphone but only 1 can be primary at most (primary is Boolean but can be also NULL)

`Contacts`:

```
cid name address
1   Jack   A
2   Bill   B
3   Mor    C
4   Jeff   D
```

`ContactsPhones`:

```
cpid cid phone  primary
1     1    140     True
2     1    150
3     2    170
```

I need to write a query that returns all contacts with their details, if they have more than 1 phone then present only primary.

Output:

```
cid name address   phone
1   Jack   A        140
2   Bill   B        170
3   Mor    C
4   Jeff   D
```

What is most easiest way to do it? 
Note that primary can have (True,False, Null)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky.  I think the easiest method is `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (cid) cid, name, address, cp.phone
FROM Contacts c LEFT JOIN
     ContactsPhones cp
     ON c.cid = cp.cpid
ORDER BY cid, (case when primary then 1 else 2 end);
```

Comment: Why do u use distinct?

Comment: @quack . . . `distinct on` is a Postgres construct which is quite handy:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT.

Comment: @quack . . . Because it chooses one row per `cid`, which is what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to a derived table that uses `ROW_NUMBER` to specify more suitable record:

```
SELECT cid, name, address, phone
FROM Contacts AS c
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT phone, cpid,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cpid
                            ORDER BY CASE 
                                        WHEN primary THEN 0
                                        ELSE 1
                                     END) AS rn
   FROM ContactsPhones) AS cp       
      ON c.cid = cp.cpid AND cp.rn = 1
```

Comment: how will it work for "Bill"? he doesn't have Primary = true in ContactsPhones. Also primary is Boolean...why text comparison?